# How to log request body using spring boot and aspect

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I have created an aspect to log the request body passed in a controller function:

This is what i am trying

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.test.test.test.controller.*.* (..))")
  public void executeController() {}

  @Pointcut("execution(* com.test.test.common.exception.*.* (..))")
  public void executeExceptionAdvice() {}

  @Pointcut("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping) || "
      + "@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping) || "
      + "@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping) ||"
      + "@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler)")
  public void logRequestMapping() {}

  @Before("logRequestMapping() && executeController() && args(..,@RequestBody requestBody) ")
  public void logRequestBody(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object requestBody) {
    LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(joinPoint.getTarget().getClass());
    LOGGER.info("Method : {},Request Body:{}",
        LOGGER.getName() + "." + joinPoint.getSignature().getName(),
        MaskingUtil.jsonifyAndMask(requestBody));
  }
```

Now instead of matching with @RequestBody spring is matching arguments with **..** i.e. generalize arguments and logging everything which is passed instead of the request body.I want to log only request body and if it is null the it won't print anything.

Comment: It would be nice if even after such a long time you would decide to provide some feedback and accept & upvote my answer if it is appropriate. I think it is. Afterwards, I can delete this comment again. It is not nice to ask questions and then ignore answers after someone else put a lot of effort in preparing a comprehensive sample for you.

Answer (score 2):

You already found my related answer, but I just noticed the link in the comment under the wrong answer here after preparing an example for you. BTW, I used pure POJO + AspectJ, not Spring AOP (only Spring libs on the classpath so as to be able to resolve the annotations), but the aspect should be the same there.

P.S.: My example is better suited to your problem because the pointcut here specifically matches target methods bearing the `@RequestBody` annotation. In the other example you would have to match all methods and then filter during runtime.

**Dummy target classes:**

I use two classes to test both of your package names. Otherwise they are the same.

```java
package com.test.test.test.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

public class MyController {
  // These should trigger the aspect
  @RequestMapping public String one(int number, @RequestBody String name) { return "Hey!"; }
  @PostMapping public void two(int number, @RequestBody String name) {}
  @PutMapping public String three(@RequestBody String name) { return "Ho!"; }
  @ExceptionHandler public void four(@RequestBody String name) {}

  // These should *not* trigger the aspect
  public String noAnnotation(@RequestBody String name) { return "No annotation"; }
  public String alsoNoAnnotation(String name) { return "Also no annotation"; }
  @RequestMapping public String five(int number, String name) { return "foo"; }
  @PostMapping public void six(int number, String name) {}
  @PutMapping public String seven(String name) { return "bar"; }
  @ExceptionHandler public void eight(String name) {}
}
```

```java
package com.test.test.common.exception;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

public class MyExceptionHandler {
  // These should trigger the aspect
  @RequestMapping public String one(int number, @RequestBody String name) { return "Hey!"; }
  @PostMapping public void two(int number, @RequestBody String name) {}
  @PutMapping public String three(@RequestBody String name) { return "Ho!"; }
  @ExceptionHandler public void four(@RequestBody String name) {}

  // These should *not* trigger the aspect
  public String noAnnotation(@RequestBody String name) { return "No annotation"; }
  public String alsoNoAnnotation(String name) { return "Also no annotation"; }
  @RequestMapping public String five(int number, String name) { return "foo"; }
  @PostMapping public void six(int number, String name) {}
  @PutMapping public String seven(String name) { return "bar"; }
  @ExceptionHandler public void eight(String name) {}
}
```

**Driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import com.test.test.common.exception.MyExceptionHandler;
import com.test.test.test.controller.MyController;

public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyController controller = new MyController();
    // These should trigger the aspect
    controller.one(1, "one");
    controller.two(2, "two");
    controller.three("three");
    controller.four("four");
    // These should *not* trigger the aspect
    controller.noAnnotation("none");
    controller.five(1, "five");
    controller.six(2, "six");
    controller.seven("seven");
    controller.eight("eight");
    controller.alsoNoAnnotation("none either");

    MyExceptionHandler handler = new MyExceptionHandler();
    // These should trigger the aspect
    handler.one(1, "one");
    handler.two(2, "two");
    handler.three("three");
    handler.four("four");
    // These should *not* trigger the aspect
    handler.noAnnotation("none");
    handler.five(1, "five");
    handler.six(2, "six");
    handler.seven("seven");
    handler.eight("eight");
    handler.alsoNoAnnotation("none either");
  }
}
```

**Aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;

@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
  @Pointcut("execution(* com.test.test.test.controller..*(.., @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody (*), ..))")
  public void executeController() {}

  @Pointcut("execution(* com.test.test.common.exception..*(.., @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody (*), ..))")
  public void executeExceptionAdvice() {}

  @Pointcut(
      "@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping) || " +
      "@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping) || " +
      "@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping) ||" +
      "@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler)"
    )
  public void logRequestMapping() {}

  @Before(
    "logRequestMapping() &&" +
    "(executeController() || executeExceptionAdvice())"
  )
  public void logRequestBody(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
    MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) thisJoinPoint.getSignature();
    Annotation[][] annotationMatrix = methodSignature.getMethod().getParameterAnnotations();
    int index = -1;
    for (Annotation[] annotations : annotationMatrix) {
      index++;
      for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
        if (!(annotation instanceof RequestBody))
          continue;
        Object requestBody = thisJoinPoint.getArgs()[index];
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
        System.out.println("  Request body = " + requestBody);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
execution(String com.test.test.test.controller.MyController.one(int, String))
  Request body = one
execution(void com.test.test.test.controller.MyController.two(int, String))
  Request body = two
execution(String com.test.test.test.controller.MyController.three(String))
  Request body = three
execution(void com.test.test.test.controller.MyController.four(String))
  Request body = four
execution(String com.test.test.common.exception.MyExceptionHandler.one(int, String))
  Request body = one
execution(void com.test.test.common.exception.MyExceptionHandler.two(int, String))
  Request body = two
execution(String com.test.test.common.exception.MyExceptionHandler.three(String))
  Request body = three
execution(void com.test.test.common.exception.MyExceptionHandler.four(String))
  Request body = four
```

Comment: I am using controller advice and aspect is not working for @ExceptionHandler.

Comment: Please be so kind to ask a new question instead of hijacking this one. Please also explain more and show an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your future question. You cannot expect me to magically "debug" one sentence of prose.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should write the full path of @RequestBody :

```
@annotation(org.springframework...RequestBody) requestBody
```

Comment: No success by using this

Comment: Finally got this:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659523/retrieve-parameter-value-from-proceedingjoinpoint